Find the sum of the real roots of the equation $f(x) = 0$ if for all real $x$ the condition $f(3x - 1) = 9x^2 - 12x$ holds.
Recently I was on math olympiad and there was this question that was worth 3 points, while the others were 2 points each. I managed to do it and I was so confident that the right answer is 2. I've got 1st place, however today my teacher said I did it wrong.
I won't share my solution so as not to confuse you, I'm curious how you would solve it.
I will repeat the problem one more time:

Find the sum of the real roots of the equation $f(x) = 0$, if for all real $x$ the condition $f(3x - 1) = 9x^2 - 12x$ holds.

Thank you in advance for any help!

The use of the word "root" rather than "solution" would seem to imply $f$ is a polynomial, but the question doesn't say so, explicitly..

My first try, which might not solve the problem, would be to set $~t = 3x-1,~$ and then try to express $~9x^2 - 12~$ as a second degree polynomial in $~t.~$

Not sure this is clear.  Are you saying that "if $x_0$ is a real number such that $f(x_0)=0$ then $f(3x_0-1)=9x_0^2-12x_0$"?  Something stronger than that?

Or are you saying that $f(3x-1)=9x^2-12x$ for all real $x$?  In any case, please edit for clarity.

@lulu, yes, for all real roots. Thanks for the correction, already fixed it.

We are given that $f(3x - 1) = 9x^2 - 12x$ and need to find the sum of the real roots of the equation $f(x) = 0$.
Identify the form of $f(x)$:
Since $f(3x - 1) = 9x^2 - 12x$, let’s try to express $f(x)$ in terms of $x$. Set $y = 3x - 1$, so that $x = \frac{y + 1}{3}$.
Rewrite $f(y)$:
Substitute $x = \frac{y + 1}{3}$ into $f(3x - 1) = 9x^2 - 12x$, giving:
$f(y) = 9 \left( \frac{y + 1}{3} \right)^2 - 12 \left( \frac{y + 1}{3} \right)$
Simplify $f(y)$:
Expanding and simplifying we will get :
$f(y) = 9 \cdot \frac{(y + 1)^2}{9} - 12 \cdot \frac{y + 1}{3}$
$f(y) = (y + 1)^2 - 4(y + 1)$  Expanding $(y + 1)^2$ and simplifying:
$f(y) = y^2 + 2y + 1 - 4y - 4$
$f(y) = y^2 - 2y - 3$
Thus, we have $f(y) = y^2 - 2y - 3$.
Solve $f(y) = 0$:
To find the roots, solve $y^2 - 2y - 3 = 0$.
Factoring this quadratic we get :
$(y - 3)(y + 1) = 0$
So, the roots are $y = 3$ and $y = -1$.
The sum of the roots $y = 3$ and $y = -1$ is:
$3 + (-1) = 2$
The sum of the real roots of the equation $f(x) = 0$ is $\boxed{2}$.
I think your answer was correct the answer is indeed 2.

Thanks for helping! However it confuses me a bit that we get a function with different value name. I mean we were asked to find roots sum of $f(x) = 0$ but instead find for $f(y) = 0$. Is it right? Surely I'm missing something obvious, aren't I?

In this problem, we use the substitution $y = 3x - 1$ to express $f$ in terms of $y$, giving us $f(y) = y^2 - 2y - 3$. This lets us find the roots easily.
Solving $f(y) = 0$ is equivalent to solving $f(x) = 0$ because the function itself remains the same—only the variable name changes temporarily. So, the sum of the roots we found for $f(y) = 0$ also applies to $f(x) = 0$.
This approach is correct, and the sum of the roots is indeed $\boxed{2}$.

Thank you for clarifying, I appreciate it! Now I understand.

Side note: You can use Vieta, then root transformation, to get the solution in ~2 lines.

This question is mind confusing.
If
$$f(3x_1-1)=9x_1^2-12x_1=0$$
$$f(3x_2-1)=9x_2^2-12x_2=0$$
then it is clear that
$$x_1+x_2=-\frac{-12}9=\frac43.$$
On the other hand $f(y_1)=f(y_2)=0$ where $y_1=3x_1-1$ and $y_2=3x_2-1.$ It is clear that the question asks $y_1+y_2.$
$$y_1+y_2=(3x_1-1)+(3x_2-1)=3(x_1+x_2)-2=3(\tfrac43)-2=2.$$

$f(3x-1)=9x^2-12x=(3x-1)^2-2(3x-1)-3$, therefore the sum of roots is $2$.

IMO, Circuit Sage did the same. Only he explained in more detail.

First of all, note that this is a second degree equation. So both are either real or complex.
Note that you have been given a function in the terms of $3 x-1$. So we define a new variable $y$ such that..
$\begin{aligned} & y=3 x-1 \\ & x=\frac{y+1}{3}\end{aligned}$
Now, the function is simple to handle.
Find the discriminant to check if the roots are real and use $-b/a$ formula to find the sum.
The easier way is to do what @Bob Dobbs did, but my follow-up question to that method would be the proof of the roots being real.
On pondering over it,
Let $f(3 x-1)=f(3[x-1/3])=g(x)$
This being a parabola, if $g(x)$ has real roots, then $f(x)$ will also have real roots, as changing of the origin along the x-axis doesn't change the fact that at some point, the graph dips below the x-axis.
If there is a rigorous proof that proves this statement, then the proof using the above mentioned method is complete.

If y= 3x- 1 the 3x= y+ 1 and x= (y+ 1)/3
so f(y)= 9(y+ 1)^2/9+ 12(y+ 1)/3= (y+ 1)^2+ 4(y+ 1)
f(y)= y^2+ 2y+ 1+ 4y+ 4= y^2+ 6y+ 5= (y+ 5)(y+ 1)= 0.
Either y+ 5= 0 so 3x- 1+ 5= 3x+ 4= 0.  x= -4/3 or
y+ 1= 0 so 3x- 1+ 1= 3x= 0. x= 0.
